# How to achieve this Beamer style?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color, logos

I think the attached slide used the following `beamer` settings:

```
\usetheme[]{Frankfurt}   % or berlin
\usecolortheme{beaver}  % red color
```

However, I have several questions:

1. How to customize the foot-line to: Topic + Author (email) + Institute + Page Number?
2. How to make the background colour of the logo matching the beamer colour theme?

My institute logo is a `JPG` file and the background colour is white. If the `beamer` theme colour is NOT white, then an area of white colour will appear in the title.

I think `SVG` file will solve this problem, but latex does not support this format. If we convert the `SVG` file to jpg/png format, the white background colour will appear again!  How to figure this out?

**Update**: including `logo` in `pdf` format solves the problem 2.

[image]

Comment: How are you introducing the author's e-mail? How exactly do you want the information in the footline to be presented (just one box containing all the info or separated boxes for the author, title, date)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I defined a `footline` template inspired by the one used by the `infolines` outer theme, containing the required fields. The new template is called myfootline and you activate it by using

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{footline}[myfootline]
   ```

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usetheme[]{Berlin}
   \usecolortheme{beaver}  % red color

   \makeatletter
   \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{myfootline}
   {
     \leavevmode%
     \hbox{%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
     \end{beamercolorbox}%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~\insertshortinstitute}
     \end{beamercolorbox}%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
       \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
     \end{beamercolorbox}}%
     \vskip0pt%
   }
   \makeatother
   \setbeamertemplate{footline}[myfootline]

   \title{The title}
   \author[The author (author@tex.sx)]{The author \\\href{mailto:author@tex.sx}{author@tex.sx}}
   \institute{The Institution}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \maketitle
   \end{frame}

   \section{A test section}
   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{A test frame title}
   test
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   And a close-up to the footline:

   [image]

   Since the `footline` now has too much information, perhaps you'll need to adjust the width of the `beamercolorbox`es used in the template.
2. As for question 2, I think it is not really on-topic here since it concerns a problem related to specifics of image formats manipulation and not to (La)TeX itself. However, in our sister site [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) you can find some answers to this question; see, for example [Add transparency to an existing PNG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/6449) or [Making the background of an image transparent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5446).

Comment: @KOF You're welcome! I did a minor edit to my answer (using `\href` for the author's e-mail).

Comment: Using the pdf-format logo solves the problem 2 :)